# How to Break lines of the displayed file names under extra large icons' miniatures at specified points in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, filenames, linebreaks

How to Break lines of the displayed file names under extra large icons' miniatures at specified points in Windows Explorer?
I want to optimize this file name display mode for the *Extra large icons view*

here is an example for a file name in one line:
__Objective__Supplier__123456789__2020-02-20-02-22-02__Title

when in Windows Explorer file name box of an icon it breaks like this:

if I'm correct after the/every 46th character it breaks the line like this:

__Objective__Supplier__123456789__2020-02-20-0

2-22-02__Title

Desired result would be  :

__*Objective__Supplier__123456789*__

2020-02-20-02-22-02

__Title

and of course these three lines would be center aligned like default

(and despite of shown above it would be NOT italic, it's only a displaying issue here on this site)

So the specified points for the line breaks are:

after the 4th __

and before the 5th __

Is there a way to make some Windows Registry Database entry that would display file names like that,
preferably only for the *Extra large icons view*
and when file names are in the above pattern like this: __text__text__text__text__text

Or if there is any other way to do this please share it

Thank you

Comment: What does "desired output" mean? If after every 34th character then maybe, if it should detect the beginning of the date then it's 100% impossible through registry.

Comment: In the first try that I aim for is to write something either Registry Database entry or something else that would tell Windows to detect the 4th instance of __ (2 pieces of underline character) in the file name, and brake the displayed line of file name after the 4th instance of __ , then tell Windows to detect the 5th instance of __  in the file name, and brake the displayed line of file name now before the 5th instance of __  in the file name. This means that this entry or script or whatever would only look up for the double_ characters, and for the 4th and 5th of them for the line break.

Comment: And this entry or script or whatever would skip all other file names with different structure than __text__text__text__text__text or __*__*__*__*__*     text could be whatever practically.
So it would only 'triggered' by the above file name pattern, then it would only break file names with this specific pattern, after the 4th __ , and before the 5th __

Comment: It does not have to detect the beginning of the date, only the 4th double_ character and 5th double_

Comment: Like I said, 100% not possible through registry then - this is a coding/scripting task, not changing a constant value in a setting database. It may be impossible overall if it's hardcoded in windows source code without any sort of access. Your best bet is to either use/create a different explorer app or to ask on StackOverflow with proper WIndows-related tags

Comment: Thanks for replying. Please help me on how to ask this on StackOverflow, because I already did it, but only got closed with -2 score. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75579049/how-to-break-lines-of-the-displayed-file-names-under-extra-large-icons-miniatur

Comment: You need to be more programming-oriented if you're asking there. So you need to ask the question for a specific Windows framework or library that is related to this task and tell people what you tried to find. It's not an easy task unfortunately so you need to do some research first. By e.g, looking at some applications that hook into Windows Explorer, like qtTabBar.

Comment: Thanks, honestly I am not qualified to do some research first, and maybe it is a bit unfair to be required some research if I could not do it. However I may understand the point of view of the site to do some research first in general - only in general. Since I simply could not do research, then how to ask it? Anyway Could you please suggest another application than qtTabBar, that would not require .NET framework to be installed?

Comment: I don't use or remember any other apps that do it in a significant way. Also,  .NET will 99% be required regardless of choice. It's the most popular framework that's used for messing with WIndows features. As for research requirement, that's unfortunately how this set of websites works - the question has to be on topic and clear effort of solving it needs to be shown.

Comment: Thanks, do you think that a Visual C++ based app for this purpose could exist?

Comment: If you're asking if anything fitting your requirements exists currently, I'd say almost surely not. If you're asking if something could be written in C++ to achieve this - maybe, I don't know too much about frameworks that let you modify Windows features, especially not C++/C.